# How to scrape the text Alpha Esports from the html using Selenium and Python

Tags: angularjs, python-3.x, selenium, xpath, css-selectors

I've recently been undertaking a personal project to improve my programming. I'm relatively new to Python.

What i'm trying to do is scrape some data( about 100-200 items) from a website. I've managed to do it for some elements but not for others. Selenium can't seem to recognize that class name.

```
<span ng-class="$ctrl.className"> Alpha Esports </span>
```

I believe the $ctrl has to do with angularjs. The span tag is contained in a div tag, as seen here:

```
<div class="ui-scoreboard-coupon-template__content--vertical-container"> <!----><div class="ui-scoreboard-coupon-template__content--vertical-aligner" ng-if="!$ctrl.viewModel.isAmericanEvent"> <div> <!----><div class="ui-scoreboard-coupon-template__cell__spacer" ng-if="!$ctrl.viewModel.inPlay"></div><!----> <!----> <div class="ui-scoreboard-coupon-template__cell"> <ui-scoreboard-runner class="ui-scoreboard-runner ui-scoreboard-runner__home" name="$ctrl.viewModel.home">
<span ng-class="$ctrl.className"> Alpha Esports </span> </ui-scoreboard-runner> </div> </div> <div class="ui-scoreboard-coupon-template__row__space"></div> <div> <!----><div class="ui-scoreboard-coupon-template__cell__spacer" ng-if="!$ctrl.viewModel.inPlay"></div><!----> <!----> <div class="ui-scoreboard-coupon-template__cell"> <ui-scoreboard-runner class="ui-scoreboard-runner ui-scoreboard-runner__away" name="$ctrl.viewModel.away">
<span ng-class="$ctrl.className"> G-Rex </span> </ui-scoreboard-runner> </div> </div> </div><!----> <!----> </div>
```

I've thought about using the xpath but it differs for each data piece and I don't know how to make 'dynamic' xpaths.
When I try to use the class name of a parent tag, it does not return any element. I've tried all of the class names that are present in the code excerpt above.

```
teams = []
teams = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("ui-scoreboard-coupon-template__content--vertical-container")
```

Finally, I thought the $ctrl might've been initialized to something earlier in the code but this is the first use of it:

```
<div class="collapsed-header collapsed-header--show" ng-show="$ctrl.showCollapsedHeader" ng-class="{'collapsed-header--show': $ctrl.showCollapsedHeader}">
    <div class="frame-layout">
        <div class="left-hand-side">
            <a class="collapsed-header__logo" ng-href="/bet" href="/bet">
              <svg class="collapsed-header__img">
                  <use xlink:href="sprite_9c5b742d050f5c4b58fe55f82f78c576.svg#logos-header_logo-usage"></use>
              </svg>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="center"></div>
        <div class="right-hand-side"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any tips regarding what to research/read up on would be much appraciated as I'm a bit overwhelmed by the angularjs concepts and selenium implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried with `XPath` and it works.Please try and let me know.

```
print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//ui-scoreboard-runner[@class='ui-scoreboard-runner ui-scoreboard-runner__home']/span").text)
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems to have worked for me. I will probably need to tweak the xpath as this only seems to pick up every other value. Thank you for your response. I will read up on xpaths.

Answer (score 0):

To extract the text **Alpha Esports**, as the element is an [Angular](https://angular.io/) element, you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *visibility of element located* and you can use either of the following solutions:

- `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  myText = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.ui-scoreboard-coupon-template__content--vertical-aligner div:nth-child(2) ui-scoreboard-runner.ui-scoreboard-runner.ui-scoreboard-runner__home>span[ng-class]"))).get_attribute("innerHTML")
  ```
- `XPATH`:

  ```
  myText = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='ui-scoreboard-coupon-template__content--vertical-aligner']//following::div[2]//ui-scoreboard-runner[@class='ui-scoreboard-runner ui-scoreboard-runner__home']/span[@ng-class]"))).get_attribute("innerHTML")
  ```
- Note: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```